# Verifying an anonymous user's display name in Firebase realtime database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm setting a display name for anonymous users, and want to make sure that new values match this set display name. The following rule is failing:

`"name": { ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.token.name" }`

Why is this? The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken) say that the display name is stored in `auth.token.name`.

Below is a full copy of my firebase rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "messages": {
        ".read": true,
        "$message": {
            ".write": "auth != null",
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['createdAt', 'text', 'user'])",

            "createdAt": { ".validate": "newData.val() == now" },
            "text": { ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0" },
            "user": {
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['_id', 'name'])",
                 "_id": { ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.uid" },
                 "name": { ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.token.name" },
            "$other": { ".validate": false }
        },
        "$other": { ".validate": false }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your full Security Rules JSON

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Just posted them. I confirmed that writes work when I switch the user.name rule to just validate newData.isString()

Comment: Are you sure you can read and write with your current rules? Because according to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade): "Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.". And I see that you've denied both read and write in your root node. So any read or write should return a permission denied error.º

Comment: It works, since the simulator read/write passes and I can get data from my app. I believe it means child rules can't revoke access, but they can grant access. I use this test payload in the simulator:```{
  "createdAt": {
    ".sv": "timestamp"
  },
  "text": "Test 1",
  "user": {
    "_id": "48c83bf9-7354-4720-838f-8b68e0addd51",
    "name": "Mike",
  }
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments (took this from [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade)):

> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules
>   can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already
>   declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

This means you won't be able to write to your database because you've declared `.write:false` at the root node of the database. You might want to remove that line to have a structure like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "messages": {
        ".read": true,
        "$message": {
            ".write": "auth != null",
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['createdAt', 'text', 'user'])",

            "createdAt": { ".validate": "newData.val() == now" },
            "text": { ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0" },
            "user": {
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['_id', 'name'])",
                 "_id": { ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.uid" },
                 "name": { ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.token.name" },
            "$other": { ".validate": false }
        },
        "$other": { ".validate": false }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The display name is indeed stored under `auth.token.name` variable. But when you use the default "Anonymous Authentication" on the Rules Simulator, this sends a request with this default auth payload:

```
{
  "provider": "anonymous",
  "uid": "N4EbtSX5HbM9JLjsW6hWT3NWzAx1"
}
```

Notice that there's no `name` specified under this payload, therefore, the `auth.token.name` variable is null and the security rule denies the write.

You can use your custom payload on the simulator, by simply changing the auth provider from "Anonymous" to "Custom" and it allows you to edit to payload, so you use this one instead:

```
{
  "provider": "anonymous",
  "uid": "N4EbtSX5HbM9JLjsW6hWT3NWzAx1",
  "token":{
    "name": "Mike"
  }
}
```

With this auth payload, the data payload you've provided in the comments should work:

```
{ 
    "createdAt": { 
        ".sv": "timestamp" 
    }, 
    "text": "Test 1", 
    "user": 
    { 
        "_id": "48c83bf9-7354-4720-838f-8b68e0addd51", 
        "name": "Mike"
    }
}
```

Comment: My previous rules are working, but I'll take a look at the changes. But too bad that the anonymous account doesn't include the set display name.

Comment: All of the providers don't include the set display name on the simulator. That's because the simulator simply takes the payloads you provide it with. It won't access your actual database/auth to check if that uid has a corresponding display name.

Comment: This I understand, but I thought the actual auth.token would include the display name

Comment: It does include it when you're testing in a real app. Just doesn't include it by default on the simulator.

Comment: I'll try the new rules and see if I can access it in the real app.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes this was a super answer. I think you should also mention in the part where you showed how to write the JSON for the custom payload in the simulator... that if someone needs to test their CustomClaims eg. **"moderator":true** or **"admin": true**, that is the place to add these KeyValue pairs(inside token{}). Cause no where in the firebase documentation is this set up mentioned. Will save developers of lots of time. Thanks again.